# expl3: \keys_set_groups:nnn and unknown keys

Tags: expl3, l3keys

I'm using `\keys_set_groups:nnn` to process only subsets of key lists. The problem is that unknown keys doesn't raise an error in this case and so typos can be overlooked easily.

I can get around it by putting every key in a "known" group and using `\keys_set_filter:nnn` first, but I wonder if there is some better way ...

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn {test} 
{
 keya .code:n =   {keya=#1~},
 keya .groups:n = {A, known},
}

%This recognize the typo keyA
\keys_set_filter:nnn {test} { known }
 {keya=test, keyA=XXX}

%this not 
\keys_set_groups:nnn {test} { A }
 {keya=abc, keyA=XXX}

\ExplSyntaxOff 
\end{document}
```

Comment: The design idea for key groups was they can be used to 'fish out' some keys from a longer list. As such, the fact that unknown keys are skipped is by-design. I can see a case for related alternatives, but to me that looks like an area for discussion: one for LaTeX-L.

Comment: @JosephWright: I do understand the rationale, but I also know how easy it is to make typos in key lists (linewidth or line width or line widht?) and so  imho if the `key_set...` doesn't do the check for known keys by default then some external command to the same effect is needed. (It is not very difficult to write such a command with `\keys_if_exist..` and `\keyval_parse:..`  so it is not a pressing matter, only a suggestion for improvement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own, say `\keys_set_groups_filter:nnn`.  Therefore I copied the definition of `\keys_set_groups:nnn` from `expl3-code.tex` and replaced the occurence of `\keys_set:nn {#1} {#3}` by `\keys_set_filter:nnn {#1} {known} {#3}`. Voilà, there's your desired error.

In the inner level you could also use `\keys_set_known:…` which rather ignores the unkown keys than raising an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \keys_set_groups_filter:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \bool_set_true:N \l__keys_selective_bool
    \bool_set_false:N \l__keys_filtered_bool
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__keys_selective_seq {#2}
    \keys_set_filter:nnn {#1} {known} {#3}
    \bool_set_false:N \l__keys_selective_bool
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_set_groups_filter:nnn { nnV , nnv , nno }

\keys_define:nn {test} 
 {
  keya .code:n =   { keya=#1~ },
  keya .groups:n = { A, known },
 }

\keys_set_groups_filter:nnn {test} { A }
 { keya=abc, keyA=XXX }

\ExplSyntaxOff 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would still have to put every key in a "known" group which looks a bit curious as l3keys knows which keys are known.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Then the only option I see is to use `\keys_set_known:…` and waive the error message.